# How to create a Mailchimp integration

Tags: integration, mailchimp

I am trying to create a Mailchimp integration that allow user to insert a section of HTML code into Mailchimp's campaign editor, similar to the integration listed in screen shot.

I have gone through Mailchimp's API but couldn't find relevant information. We have also contacted Mailchimp support. All they can provide is link to API which I had already read through.

Any pointer to where to start is appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn5UZ.png)

Thank you!
Q.

I have tried to find relevant info in https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/, but couldn't find the information needed.

Comment: Just found I didn't name the screen shot link. Here is the link to the screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn5UZ.png